# [not-working] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

Do we really need the [not-working](/questions/tagged/not-working) tag on Stack Overflow? It sounds similar to the blacklisted tags [problem](/questions/tagged/problem) and [question](/questions/tagged/question) which were previously banned. Maybe somebody can ban [not-working](/questions/tagged/not-working) too.

Comment: and ban the error tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Agreed, both [not-working](/questions/tagged/not-working) and [error](/questions/tagged/error) are now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem [not-working](/questions/tagged/not-working) add anything to the question being asked, in the same way [problem](/questions/tagged/problem) doesn't.
Rather than making the tag a synonym of another tag, I would block it.

Answer (score -4):

Seems like we should just make [not-working](/questions/tagged/not-working) a synonym for [error](/questions/tagged/error)... which I just suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/error/synonyms).

**EDIT:**

Since none of the downvoters have left any comments, I'm left to guess wildly about what they are disagreeing with. Perhaps they don't like the fact that I am suggesting we get rid of one rarely-used meta tag by making it a synonym of a frequently-used (although still kind of meta) tag. They *are* synonyms, since if something is "not working" it implies some kind of error/mistake/problem.

If people don't like the existence of the [error](/questions/tagged/error) tag and want to dispute its existence, then that should be brought up elsewhere as neither the question nor my answer are focused on that matter. I don't see any problem condensing meta tags via synonyms. It's something the community can easily do itself without having to petition a moderator for blacklisting. It also means there will be fewer tags to deal with later if we decide the dominant synonym is too meta and should be removed.

If anyone has any thoughts on the matter, I'd like to hear them.

Comment: Isn't the whole site about errors?

Comment: @random: Much of it, but there's also "explain this to me", "how do I do this", "is there a better way to do this", etc. types of questions that aren't related to an exception or bug.

Comment: @gnostradamus I'm not the one who downvote this. But I'm not really like to be this a synonym for [error]. Tags like [error] and [problem] are not really adding valuable information to the question, when you see it in the question list on the main page of SO, and in my opinion they should be banned

Comment: @igor milla: That's all well and good, but banning [not-working] will probably just drive users to use similar established tags, like the ubiquitous [error] tag (currently used on 6,597 questions). Until [error] is gone, banning similar tags isn't likely to do anything more than the alternative of stopping them through making them a synonym.

Comment: @gnostradamus good point, but for the some reasons, community decided to ban problem tag, maybe it's a way to go

Comment: I agree with @igor that [tag:error] adds nothing, and I can't imagine anyone following that tag.