# The [error] tag has come back to life!

Tags: support, tags, tag-block-request

On [June 19th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95513/not-working-tag), the meta tag [error](/questions/tagged/error) was burninated with righteous fire.  However, it seems that this step wasn't quite enough.  Someone recreated it yesterday, and there are now over 20 questions associated with it.

While it will be trivial to simply edit the tag out of those questions, the tag itself should be destroyed, blacklisted, nuked from orbit, made obsolete, murdered, obliterated, or perhaps banned.

Or something to keep it from coming back to life.

Comment: Completely agreed. I just mentioned this tag in my topic about improper tagging. Heh.

Comment: it should also be folded, spindled, and mutilated.

Comment: I assume this is an [error].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are currently no questions with the tag for which blacklisting is being requested.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated **and blacklisted**.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: This image needs scalps.

Comment: @random How about shredded, charred scraps of SO tags scattered around Trogdor's feet?