# Can the "error" (meta-)tag please be burninated?

Tags: support, tags, meta

[error](/questions/tagged/error) does not seem to serve a purpose (like it didn't serve any on SO and SU) here on Meta. There are only 35 questions tagged with it, but I'd hate to edit all of them just to remove that tag (and disrupt the frontpage with that).

Can one of you mods please take care of this?

Comment: Maybe make [meta-tag:error] a synonym of [meta-tag:support]?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA It could be a synonym of [meta-tag:bug] too, but I don't see the necessity of making it a synonym.

Comment: Argh, got confused.  Thought we were talking about [non-meta error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97187/the-error-tag-has-come-back-to-life), which is blacklisted.  (You may thus decline my confused edit proposal...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) has eaten these up in the state of merging.

```
updating post history, 96 rows affected
updating posts, 66 rows affected
tag remapping of [bug] and [error] complete!
```

Reasons that tag was used included:

- error message seen on the 404 page, CAPTCHA or another method
- support issues
- bug reports
- the use of the tag on Stack Overflow
- just because

No synonym has been created.