# Blacklisting a tag with synonyms breaks a few things

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms, blocked-tags

According to Jeff's answer to [The [error] tag has come back to life!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97187/the-error-tag-has-come-back-to-life) the [error](/questions/tagged/error) tag is blacklisted.

I've been removing [errors](/questions/tagged/errors), which is a really pointless tag, but have noticed a few strange things.

1. [errors](/questions/tagged/errors) exists despite [error](/questions/tagged/error) being blacklisted.
2. Leaving [errors](/questions/tagged/errors) on a question when editing results in the following error message:

   > [image]
3. The [tag page of a blacklisted tag returns a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/error/info) but the synonym of that tag uses the original tag page as its own.

   > [image]

From all of this I'm assuming that [errors](/questions/tagged/errors) was a synonym of [error](/questions/tagged/error) when it was blacklisted. I think that when a tag gets blacklisted it's synonyms should be burninated or unsynonymised.

I've left the last few [errors](/questions/tagged/errors) tags available for experimentation in the name of science.