# It's time to blacklist [library]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

The tag [library](/questions/tagged/library) was [burninated by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/128315/229) during the 2012 Great Tag Removal Thingymajig.

Since that fateful morn<sup>1</sup> it's been re-created most days by people with more reputation than tagging ability. It then gets re-used by people with no reputation, but still more than they have tagging ability, on a near constant basis.

It's generally used by people affiliated to the "let's make a sentence when tagging" school of thought. The most recent two:

- *Android Library project organization*, [andriod](/questions/tagged/andriod) [project](/questions/tagged/project) [library](/questions/tagged/library)
- *Java library for character sequence generator*, [java](/questions/tagged/java) [library](/questions/tagged/library)

All it means is *"I am using a library"*, the answer to which is *"great, **which**?"*, or *"I want to find a library"*, the answer to which is *"care to describe your actual problem?"*. There should never be a situation where a tag this vague is considered needful.

I remove this tag constantly but it [keeps](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20071475/revisions) coming back like the ugly wart it is. Can the blacklist be brought down upon this?

<sub>1. 9am UTC, he must have been up late.</sub>

Comment: +1 for "_more reputation than tagging ability_," Tell us what you really think.

Comment: AFAIK the system can't automatically destroy a tag which has a synonym attached to it, and this one has a useless [tag:libary] synonym attached to it... What the f***?

Comment: All that demonstrates is how bad things were before it got killed @animuson :-). I'm a little surprised that you can't blacklist a tag with a synonym because of [what I noticed with errors](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182092/blacklisting-a-tag-with-synonyms-breaks-a-few-things)

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about @george, this is me being circumspect :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: You can blacklist it. What I'm saying is that it never gets *truly deleted*. We had this same problem with the [tag:web-development] tag before, because it had a synonym on it.

Comment: Of course @animuson, how else would the system know not to use it? That's fairly standard among all suppressions systems. I'm more excited by your allusion to [tag:web-development] being blacklisted? Can it be true? [tag:game-development] caused me a lot of pain, and it's together with the web in [this blacklist request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148168/blacklist-web-development-web-developer-and-related-tags/), which might now be status completed?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: I don't think it was ever blacklisted, and that question was probably a result of the tag not getting deleted properly. If the tag never gets deleted, then *anyone* can always use the tag, even at 1 rep. It doesn't require the 1,500 tag creation privilege, and the tag still appears in the tag recommendations box. *That's* the problem here. If people keep seeing it, they will use it. The tag needs to be killed off *properly* first, which AFAIK requires removing that synonym on it.

Comment: Ah, I see @animuson, that makes more sense. Is there a bug report you know of that I can upvote?

Comment: I don't think one has ever been filed. But a simple feature-request to kill off all synonyms for a tag when it gets burninated by a moderator would probably suffice.

Comment: I don't know what's more incredible [read: horrifying], that `library` actually has followers (35 currently) or that the tag `libary` exists...

Comment: Stack Overflow: Where we burn [books] and blacklist [library].

Comment: Don't worry Yannis both [books](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) and [library](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library) are on Programmers. You can carry the torch forward for us :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Thanks. Just got home from the stadium, where <local sports team> suffered an embarrassing home loss, and we probably lost the chance to play in next year's Champions League. Was looking for something to do to vent my frustration and satisfy my bloodlust.

Comment: Sorry about PAOK @Yannis (nothing is sacred on the interwebs). But, plus side, if you'd got through to the final you might have had to watch thousands of Londoner's tutting at your compatriots for blocking escalators and pavements so it's not all bad :-).

Comment: [tag:libary] synonym deleted.

Comment: [Just like \[server\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139869/its-time-to-blacklist-server), I keep `library` on my list of 47 tags that I check on every day to make sure it stays depopulated.  Sigh.

Comment: It's your turn again then @Charles. Do you want to ask for [tag:value] to be blacklisted :-)?

Comment: `value` is already on my list of evil, @ben.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been added to the blacklist, since there was an overwhelming consensus and like that crazy cat, it kept coming back.

WHY DO YOU PEOPLE HATE LIBRARIES? Don't you know those are the only places where some kids have access to books? Sheesh.

Comment: I think I love you! Happily accepted :-). Charles won't know what to do with himself