# Should the [crash], [crashes] tags be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

IMHO, [crash](/questions/tagged/crash) (2066) and [crashes](/questions/tagged/crashes) (65) describe symptoms of an [error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95513/not-working-tag), and is perhaps a borderline meta tag.

Similar tags: [[error] and [not-working]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95513/not-working-tag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
crash != p0rbelm
```

I am not sure what world you are living in, but in ***mine*** they are not the same **at all**

A `crash` implies that something actually *crashed* in the program.
A `p0rbelm` implies nothing. **nothing at all**. Just that the question was asked.

---

As it says in the [crash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crash/info):

> A crash is the result of an unrecoverable error that causes the program to stop completely. During the software development, crashes can be avoided by implementing proper error and exception handling.

Comment: I agree. Ideally, folks would use an exception name when that's available, but "crash" still has some meaning.

Comment: OK, my bad for choosing a bad example tag. My point is, a crash is simply a result of an error (in loose terms, a problem) and the cause/solution is relative to the technology at hand.

Comment: While trying to rephrase the question, I convinced myself that you're right. Bah.