# Make [crashing] a synonym of [crash]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

The [crashing](/questions/tagged/crashing) tag has the same meaning as [crash](/questions/tagged/crash) so it should be made a synonym.

Comment: <sarcasm>Since `*-ing` ususally denotes an action, I'm going to guess that it is for people with urgent questions since it means their application is crashing at the moment</sarcasm>

Comment: Is there a reason why either of these tages are even needed?

Comment: @JoshMein There was a related discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116849/should-the-crash-crashes-tags-be-burninated)

Comment: I agree with Josh, synonymize them ... with fire. There are [way too many questions about crashes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=crash+is%3Aquestion), and it doesn't add much, if any, value.